# What's the reason of using ; in F# lists instead of ,?

Tags: list, syntax, f#

This might be a strange question but if I want to define a list of integers from:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Do I need to do it using the `;` character?

```
[ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9 ]
```

instead of?:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
```

It just seems to me `,` is more natural and easy on the eyes. Just wondering the idea behind using `;`? (Not criticizing)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes you must.  The reason why is that in F# the comma operator is used for tuple expressions.  So the expression `1,2,...9` is interpreted as a single tuple with 9 values.

```
[1,2] // List with 1 element that is a tuple value - (int*int) list
[1;2] // List with 2 elements that are integer values - int list
```

Comment: Thanks Jared, then the reason , is used for tuples is because defining literal tuples is more common than defining literal lists, right?

Comment: @Joan I don't know the history of this choice other than it's a hold over from OCaml.

Comment: Note that in OCaml, calling `f(x,y)` means calling `f` with a single argument that is a tuple `(x,y)`.  Parameter lists probably are more common that list literals, if one wants to posit the 'most common should use commas' rationale.

Comment: Thanks Brian, can you please tell me what parameter lists are? Lists like [1;2;3]?

Comment: I think Brian meant by parameter lists the list of parameters (arguments) passed to a function. They are called list in almost all languages so you call a function `f` of two parameters using the syntax `f(x,y)`. However in OCaml and F# such a call is passing a tuple to a function of a single parameter. This makes the use of tuples more common. In short, tuples (used as parameters) are more common than list literals in F#/OCaml.

Comment: Note that if F# had tuple syntax like Python where tuples have parens around them, you could have commas between list items.

Comment: @Gabe: It does; there is parens around them. I have always wondered about the point that you made.

Answer (score 15):

Other answers have pointed out the main reason.

As an aside it is worth noting that, like most other places that semicolon is used in the language, an alternative is a newline.  For example

```
[ "foo"; "bar"; "baz" ]
```

can also be written as

```
[ "foo"
  "bar"
  "baz" ]
```

or a variety of other layouts where semicolons are replaced by newlines.

Answer (score 8):

`[1,2,3,4,5]` is a list of 1 element of type int * int * int * int * int

`[1;2;3;4;5]` is a list of 5 elements of type int

also, list comprehensions and ranges are your friends

`let bar = [1..9]`, 1..9 is a range so it get's unfolded into 1;2;3;...9;

`let blort = [for i in 1..9 -> i]` is a comprehension that does the same thing -- a little more power for some performance issues.

Edit: for completeness sake, you can also do

```
let foo = [1
           2
           3]
```

and get a list of [1;2;3]

Comment: Thanks, why is there perf penalty for [1..9]? Isn't the compiler just unfolds it to [1;2;3...9]?

Comment: in the case of [1..9] there shouldn't be, but list comprehensions can get quite complicated i.e. [for i in 1 .. 9 -> i * i], I have tried to use nested for loops in list comprehensions and had some substantial problems

Sequences on the other hand worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, by "substantial problems" you mean perf problems? Also so [1..9] unfolds at compile time but [for i in 1 .. 9 -> i * i] is unfolded at runtime? Or are they all executed at runtime?

Comment: Oh wow, thanks. Can you really do [1 2 3] to get [1;2;3]? Then it's even better. Way better. Thanks again.

Comment: sorry about the formatting, that should get the point across, as above you can use new lines to delimit a list

Answer (score 5):

> Just wondering the idea behind using ;?

Tuples are more common in ML and using `;` lets you write lists of tuples as:

```
[1, 2; 3, 4]
```

Historically, F# inherited this syntax from OCaml which created its syntax by trying to remove more superfluous parentheses from Standard ML syntax.